# What is the right way to chain calls to services in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

I need to invoke a Restful service endpoint to get an Id and once I got the result I should invoke a second Restful service endpoint through a angularjs service.
First call returns a customer ID, with this customer ID I need to search for additional info about that customer.

As I should call and and wait for promises I don't think nesting calls to promises is a good pratice. What I mean is that something like the below code isn't supposed to be a neat solution. Am I right or wrong? What should be a good way to achieve this task.

```
someService.someAction().then( function(data){
   var id = data.data;
   antoherCallToAnotherService.someOtherAction(id).then(function(data2){
         //do some stuff
   );
 );
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite typical approach. However, you can optimise it by chaining multiple promises:

```
someService.someAction().then(function(response) {
    var id = response.data;
    return antoherCallToAnotherService.someOtherAction(id);
})
.then(function(data2) {
    // data is available
});
```

This is not that bad at all, however can be improved even more if you want. You should probably not make the first promise resolve with entire `response` object, underlying service should resolve with actual (maybe processed data). Then your code could become:

```
someService.someAction()
.then(antoherCallToAnotherService.someOtherAction)
.then(function(data) {
    // data is available
});
```

For above to work, `someService.someAction` should resolve with `response.data` (which is an `id` in your case).